# publish video on azure media services

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I've managed to upload an MP4 file to the BLOB container associated with my Azure media services account. I want to know if my next course of action should be to try and publish the video? if so how would I do that by referencing the BLOB where the video is stored. Could someone show me an example of how this is done?

Comment: If you've found one of the answers to be helpful, please mark them as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could also publish directly to Azure Media Services, in which case it will generate a generic BLOB container for you, and your file will be ready to go.

[I have a tutorial series here.](http://www.davevoyles.com/uploading-video-to-azure-media-services/) I do not do this programatically, however. Let me know if you ned any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to upload your video to the container after that you need to encode your video there are many formats available Smooth Streaming, HLS etc... after that you need to publish your video to be available for streaming.

if you want to do this programmatically you can use Azure Media Services SDK for . net

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/media-services/developer-tools/

if you  want to do this using the portal  you can follow this tutorial but you have a big limitation you can upload maximum a video with 200 mb of size.

here you can see the two ways to upload and publish your videos

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn735908.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Azure Media Services will create an asset entity and link that to the blob container you are using to upload asset files. By publishing the asset, our streaming service would know which blob container to look into to retrieve those Mp4 files. Once your file is encoded or uploaded into the blob storage as an Asset entity (you need to use Azure Media Services SDK to upload the file), then you are good to publish the asset. Please remember to turn up 1 streaming unit if you want to use dynamic packaging feature.